# Appium Inspector doesnt start an gives Time out error

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-inspector

I am trying to open an application to use for appium inspector with xcode simulator. However i provide capabilities and open server then press start session. Simulator opens, app downloaded and wdio downloaded but it never opens app and gives "Request Time Out" problem.

"platformName": "iOS",
"appium:platformVersion": "16.4",
"appium:deviceName": "iPhone 14",
"appium:automationName": "XCUITest",
"appium:bundleId": "com."there is bundle".dev",
"appium:udid": "378717F9-D6A4-463F-A50A-2C0647A3E6AE",
"appium:app": "/Users/eyup/Desktop//BKT/App.app"

This is appium server response

Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8100/session] with body: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"bundleId":"com."there is bundle".dev","arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true,"shouldTerminateApp":true,"forceAppLaunch":true,"useNativeCachingStrategy":true,"forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence":false}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}
[XCUITestDriver@09e0 (d2f6f79b)] Got response with status 500: {"value":{"error":"session not created","message":"Cannot launch com."there is bundle".dev application. Make sure the correct bundle identifier has been provided in capabilities and check the device log for possible crash report occurrences","traceback":""},"sessionId":null}
[debug] [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'session not created' to SessionNotCreatedError
[debug] [XCUITestDriver@09e0 (d2f6f79b)] Failed to create WDA session (A new session could not be created. Details: Cannot launch com."there is bundle".dev application. Make sure the correct bundle identifier has been provided in capabilities and check the device log for possible crash report occurrences). Retrying...
[debug] [XCUITestDriver@09e0 (d2f6f79b)] Event 'wdaSessionAttempted' logged at 1696068102477 (13:01:42 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00))
[debug] [XCUITestDriver@09e0 (d2f6f79b)] Sending createSession command to WDA
[debug] [XCUITestDriver@09e0 (d2f6f79b)] Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
[debug] [XCUITestDriver@09e0 (d2f6f79b)] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8100/session] with body: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"bundleId":"com."there is bundle".dev","arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true,"shouldTerminateApp":true,"forceAppLaunch":true,"useNativeCachingStrategy":true,"forceSimulatorSoftwareKeyboardPresence":false}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}